# Force a div to grow wider than the browser window

Tags: html, css, css-float

How can I force a DIV to grow wider than the browser window to accommodate it's children horizontally, rather than forcing them on new rows

i.e. consider the following code with fiddle. There are 6 child elements inside of a container element, all with a minimum width of 200px, and all set to float: left. When the window is resized wide enough they are all on one row. When it is narrowed, they start pushing to new rows. Ideally I would like them to remain on a single row and have the browser display a scroll bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/krippy2k/x8sDp/20/

```
.container {
}

.child-element {
    min-width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}

.child1 {
    background-color: purple;
}
.child2 {
    background-color: orange;
}
.child3 {
    background-color: black;
}
.child4 {
    background-color: green;
}
.child5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.child6 {
    background-color: red;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="child-element child1"></div>
    <div class="child-element child2"></div>
    <div class="child-element child3"></div>
    <div class="child-element child4"></div>
    <div class="child-element child5"></div>
    <div class="child-element child6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either you can provide a `width` to the parent element, else you can use `float: left;` with `display: inline-block;` and `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.container {
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-element {
    min-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x8sDp/22/)

For the `white-space` of `4px` between each element, you can use `margin-left: -4px;`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/x8sDp/23/)

Comment: I had basically the same question as the OP, and this answer was the best solution. Something I added was floating the container. This gave the container the width of it's children rather than the width of the containers bounding box.

Comment: The white-space between the elements is actually the physical white-space (spaces, tabs, newlines) in the html (reduced to a single space) between the child tags, rendered in whatever font/size that has cascaded down. To eliminate this, you can set `font-size:0;` in the container, remembering to explicitly set it if needed in the children.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of floating the children, set them to inline block and set `white-space:nowrap` on the container.

```
.container {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.child-element {
    display:inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8sDp/24/

Comment: IMHO this is a better solution as floating can have unintentional consequences to the rest of the layout, as it essentially takes the element out of the flow of the rest of the page structure. Often times floating creates a bit of a marionette situation that is hard to manage.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `.container` to `display:table` and the `.child-elements` to be `display:table-cell` and remove `float:left` from `.child-element`:

```
.container {
    display: table;
}

.child-element {
    min-width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x8sDp/26/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a huge width to the container works

```
.container {
  width: 999999px;
}
```

Though im not sure why you would want to do something like this, from a usability/interface point of view.

Comment: FYI it's for a workflow designer which can have many levels of nested elements. Certain elements are meant to be side-by-side, such as Then/Else clauses, which become more difficult to read when the Else is forced underneath the Then.

Comment: I see, wouldn't some form of tree view be preferable? i don't really know what you are doing but imo horizontal + vertical scrolling usually result in very confusing interfaces, unless your target is touch screens. Again, this is a rather uninformed opinion.

Comment: I thought about a tree but it would be annoying because of the amount of dragging and dropping that is needed. To be productive with it while designing and troubleshooting, the tree would really need to remain fully expanded anyway, which would leave us with the same problem. The Workflow Foundation designer in Visual Studio 2012 is pretty similar to what I'm going for.